# TwoSum Swift Solution

Tags: swift, sum

I just started learning coding with swift, and was trying TwoSum.

"Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1]."

I found some solutions from GitHub that I cannot understand.

code is from https://github.com/soapyigu/LeetCode-Swift/blob/master/Array/TwoSum.swift

```
class TwoSum {
    func twoSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
        var dict = [Int: Int]()

        for (i, num) in nums.enumerated() {
            if let lastIndex = dict[target - num] {
                return [lastIndex, i]
            }
            dict[num] = i
        }
        fatalError("No valid outputs")
    }
}
```

Could someone be so kind to explain to codes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good site for a question like this. Please narrow your question down to one clear and specific question or issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dict` initialised in the method stores the numbers in the input as keys, and their indices as values. The program uses this to remember which number is where. The `dict` can tell you things like "the number 2 is at index 0".

For each number `num` at index `i` in the input array, we subtract `num` from the `target` to find the other number that we need, in order for them to add up to `target`.

Now we have the other number we need, we check to see if we have seen such a number before, by searching `dict`. This is what the `if let lastIndex = dict[target - num]` part is doing. If the `dict` knows what index the other number is at, we return that index, and `i`.

If we haven't seen that number before, we record `i` into the dictionary under the key `num`, hoping that in later iterations, we can find a number that when added to `num`, makes 9.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and I will try to raise my question quality. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of integers, return **indices** of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

```
var arr:[Int] = []
func twoSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var toggle = false
    for i in 0..<nums.count {
        for j in i+1..<nums.count {
            if toggle == false {
                if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
                    toggle = true
                    arr.insert(i, at: 0)
                    arr.insert(j, at: 1)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].

Answer (score 0):

In Sweeper's excellent answer, he explained what dict is used for: It lets you use a value from the array to find that value's index. It would be more obvious what the dictionary was used for if we called it `indexes`, and this code builds the same dictionary in a more explicit way:

```
var indexes = [Int: Int]()

for index in 0..<array.count {
    let value = array[index]
    indexes[value] = index
}
```

After that, you get a dictionary:

```
[2:0, 7:1, 11:2, 15:3]
```

You could write the function this way:

```
func twoSum(_ array: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var indexes = [Int: Int]()

    for index in 0..<array.count {
        let value = array[index]
        indexes[value] = index
    }

    for index in 0..<array.count {
        let value = array[index]
        if let otherIndex = indexes[target - value],
           index != otherIndex {
            return [index, otherIndex]
        }
    }
    fatalError("Unable to match values")
}
```

That is a much more long-winded (and less efficient) way of doing the same thing. It loops through the array twice instead of once, but the results should be the same.

Comment: Good catch on the typo and the `[1, 1]` degenerate result. I'll add a fix to prevent that. The point of my code is to illustrate what the OP's "mystery code' is doing in a more long-winded, easier-to-follow form.

Answer (score 0):

```
func twoSum(array: [Int], target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var dict = [Int:Int]()
    for (index, number) in array.enumerated() {
        let value = target - number 
        if let sum = dict[value] {
            return [sum, index]
        }
        dict[number] = index
    }
    return [0,0]
}
/*
array=[1, 2, 3] -> target=4
 enumerated() => [0,1], [1,2], [2,3]
 (i, n)
 v4 - 1 = 3
 s[3:0]
 s[3:0]
 v4 - 2 = 2
 s[2:0]
 s[2:1]
 v4 - 3 = 1
 s[1:1]
 s[1:2]
 output [0,2]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers: [Int] = [1, 3, 6, 7, 7, 14, 12]
var target = 26
var result = [Int]()
for i in 0..<numbers.count {
    for j in i+1..<numbers.count {
        if numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target {
            print(numbers[i],numbers[j])
            result.append(i)
            result.append(j)
        }
        }
}
print(Array(Set(result)))
```

Comment: I am also learning swift. Started writing solutions in brute force method for some problems. Hope this will be easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
func twoSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var dict:[Int:Int] = [:]

    for i in 0..<nums.count {
        if dict[target - nums[i]] != nil {
            return [dict[target - nums[i]] ?? 0, i]
        } else {
            dict[nums[i]] = i
        }
    }

    return [0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the discussion section of the TwoSum problem on Leetcode.

Lots of great Swift solutions there.
https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=swift.

My personal two cents -

```
func twoSumA(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] { 
    
    var numsHashMap: Dictionary<Int, Int> = [:]
    var outputArr: [Int] = []
    
    for index in 0..<nums.count {
        let currentNum = nums[index]
        
        if numsHashMap.keys.contains(target-currentNum) {
            outputArr.append(numsHashMap[target-currentNum] ?? -1)
            outputArr.append(index)
            return outputArr
        }
        numsHashMap[currentNum] = index
    }
    return !outputArr.isEmpty ? outputArr : [-1, -1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func twoSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result: [Int] = [Int]()
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    while i < nums.count - 1 {
        j = i + 1
        while j <= nums.count - 1{
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                result.append(i)
                result.append(j)
                break
            }
            j += 1
            }
        i = i + 1
    }
    return result
       }
```